# UITableView Controller with prototype custom cell and search display controller tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

is there a way I can have in the search results controller  table view the exact same styling (height, background etc) I have in the prototype cell of my tableview controller in iOS5?

The root view has a background picture and a specific cell height. The search table does not appear with the background picture and the cell height is lower;

Comment: Actually it was easy.

Just use

-(void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
and put styling code there

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to just use the same cell identifier (at least if you're using storyboards), so for example:

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"searchCell";
myCustomCell *cell = (myCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

//for search controller need to check if cell is nil, if it is create one since there won't be any to reuse to begin with
if (!cell) {
    cell = (myCustomCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
}
```

Other properties such as row heights etc can be set by accessing properties of

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView
```