# How to use "sublists" in a UITableView and with a search bar?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell, uisearchbar, show-hide

What I want to do is the following : it would be basically a table view displaying some cells with many values.

[image]

When a value-cell is chosen, it opens new cells with subvalues from the value of the chosen one.

[image]

It would also let the user able to make a search between these cells.

[image]

I've already used a lot UITableViews so I've no problem with selecting, displaying data, handling events etc.
I never used a table view with a search bar but from what I've red in many tutorials it doesn't look that complicated.
So there are only 2 points on which I need your help.

- What is the best way to display these new cells when value cells are tapped (and of course hide them again in case of re-tapped value cell).
- The most tricky point seems to be here, how can I use the search bar to look ONLY for data in value cells and not in subvalue ones? For example, if a user has already tapped and opened subvalues from values 2 and 5, if he inserts "2" in the search bar, the cell with value "5" and all its subvalue cells will be hidden, but the "2" one will keep being displayed with its subvalues.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way to display these new cells when value cells are
>   tapped (and of course hide them again in case of re-tapped value
>   cell).

Simplest way is to add more rows to your data array when you expand a cell, and remove them on collapse. Customize the look of "sub-list cells" and keep track of which cell is currently expanded. You can also look into using https://github.com/OliverLetterer/UIExpandableTableView (I haven't used it, so can't really comment on it).

> The most tricky point seems to be here, how can I use the search bar
>   to look ONLY for data in value cells and not in subvalue ones? For
>   example, if a user has already tapped and opened subvalues from values
>   2 and 5, if he inserts "2" in the search bar, the cell with value "5"
>   and all its subvalue cells will be hidden, but the "2" one will keep
>   being displayed with its subvalues.

This is the easier part, I would say. You are responsible for searching the table view data and providing a filtered list to the search display controller. This is done through these two methods:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText: searchString
                               scope: [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles][[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText: [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text]
                               scope: [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles][searchOption]];
    return YES;
}
```

In the `filterContentForSearchText:scope:` method, search only the "super-list cells", not "sub-list cells". You can customize the search display table's cell's to make it look like super list/sub list: [UITableView Controller with prototype custom cell and search display controller tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650257/uitableview-controller-with-prototype-custom-cell-and-search-display-controller)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to display these new cells when value cells are tapped (and of course hide them again in case of re-tapped value cell).

Take a look at the [TLIndexPathTools project](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools) on GitHub. It makes it easy to build dynamic tables like this with minimal effort. Most notably, it does the batch updates automatically to animate between states. There are several example projects, the most similar to your situation is the [collapsable "Outline" project](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Outline/Outline/OutlineTableViewController.m).